# overlay resize with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a popup overlay that I'm currently resizing with some jquery code. I'm looking to change this implementation to work only with CSS. This is the general setup I have along with the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezSru/)**

```
<div id="BigDiv"></div>
<div id="Overlay"></div>

#Overlay{
    background:red;
    opacity:0.6;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%}

#BigDiv{
    height:2000px;
    width:2000px;
    background:blue;}
```

As you can see, the overlay is sized at 100% width and height so when the user looks at the overlay, it fills the screen. However, when the user scrolls, the overlay isn't resized. How can I change this to make the resize work only with CSS, if at all possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) instead of `absolute` which will place the overlay at a

> specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled

You can keep the `width:100%;height:100%` or use a full `top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;` positioning system - both should make the overlay cover the whole viewport.

Comment: oh sweet!!! I also reposition the popup on scroll so scrolling triggers both the resize and the repositioning so it's a bit jerky; now it's fluid, thanks!